# What requirements are needed for a soldier to use the Gollop Chamber?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

How do you get a psionic soldier who's powerful enough to use the Gollop Chamber that you've built?

Answer (score 8):

You need a Psi Suit for your Psycho Soldier. If you don't have one yet, you have to first test them for Psi abilities.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't need to be wearing the psi suit as long as they have the level 3 psi ability unlocked and a high enough Will.

Comment: @Shadur nope, no suit = no volunteer (unless 114 will isn't high enough).